# Not getting desired output in Oracle

Tags: oracle

Table creation query:

```
create table students(
student_no       number,
student_name     varchar2(20),
student_addres   varchar2(25),
student_dob      date
joining_time     date
)
```

Insert query:

```
insert into students 
values (1,'ram','chittoor',to_date('02/04/2012','dd/mm/yyyy'),to_date('01:21:45','hh:mi:ss))
```

result:1 row inserted

Query to check insert:

```
select * from students
```

Result:

```
student_no student_name  student_address  student_dob  joining_date
.......... ............  ...............  ...........  ............

1          ram           chittoor          2-apr-2012  1-jul-2012
```

Qhy are the time values not getting inserted properly?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/87bcf/1

Comment: Check your db session date format by 'select sysdate from dual;'

Comment: but that kind of out put(joining_date) am not getting @naveen

Comment: i checked but it showing 31-JUL-13...

Comment: Change session by using: alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF'

Comment: this session is only permit to current session only

Comment: alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF.i exicute this query but showing error..SQL Error: ORA-01821: date format not recognized
01821. 00000 -  "date format not recognized"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: view my posted answer

Comment: ya i saw..thanq for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is [working example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d371a/3)

If you want to get the **Time** from joining_time column then your,

Select query should be

```
SELECT student_no,
   student_name,
   student_addres,
   student_dob,
   TO_CHAR (joining_time, 'hh:mi:ss') AS joining_time
FROM students
```

Comment: i got my desired out with your query..thanq for helping me

Comment: i have one more doubt can you clarify that plesae

Comment: you mentioned each and every column name in selecting query. if possible with out mention column names give query for my desired out put

Comment: Thats called alias names, i set alias for table name and get the column values by using it...

Answer (score 1):

Your date is inserted properly, the tool you're using just seems to show the date without the time potion, check your tool settings;

Oracle has no support for Time only format, only date and time. Here is an excerpt from Oracle type [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#autoId19):

> In a time-only entry, the date portion defaults to the first day of
>   the current month

Which is the case, you you get 1-July.

Based on this info, you'll need to rethink your queries.

Comment: how to write query for date and time..give an query and example please

Comment: Well if you want to make sure your "time" got inserted correctly, try this query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fb0e8/4
I was suggesting that you modify your logic to query based on the fact that the joining_time is a "full date".
I can give you queries if you tell me what exactly do you want to accomplish

Comment: your query showing only time.its good.see my above inserting query..my desired out put as               student_no student_name  student_address  student_dob  joining_date
.......... ............  ...............  ...........  ............
 
1          ram           chittoor          2-apr-2012    01:21:45     for this purpose give me query